# Fulltext search with pipe

Tags: angular

Is it possible to create a fulltext search over an array of objects with a pipe?

I start with implementing a search for a single field

```ts
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any): any {
      return value.filter((item) => item.company.startWith('s'));
    }
}
```

But get the following error

```
core.umd.js:3488 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./CustomerListComponent class CustomerListComponent - inline template:17:20 caused by: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
```

**Update**

Component

```ts
export class CustomerListComponent {

  public customers:any;

  constructor(
    private customerService: CustomerService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.customerService.getCustomers()
      .subscribe(data => this.customers = data)
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<tr *ngFor="let customer of customers | search">
    <td>{{customer.id}}</td><td><a [routerLink]="['/profile', customer.id]">{{customer.company}}</a></td>...
</tr>
```

Module

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, CustomerListComponent, CustomerProfileComponent, SearchPipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: share your code of compoennt and html to show how you have used pipe

Comment: @ranakrunal9 done! is this enough?

Comment: It looks like the value you're trying to filter with the pipe is not yet initialized on first render, since you're grabbing it asynchronously via a service. You should add a `if` clause around it to not filter, if it's `null`.

Comment: Or expose the observable and use `| async` to resolve it asynchronously in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its giving you error because there is no value assigned to `customers` initially and when you call API may be results are empty.

// Component

```
public customers:any[] = [];
```

// Single index search

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
    return (typeof value !== 'undefined') ? value.filter((item) => item.company.startWith('s')) : true;
  }
}
```

// Multiple index search

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
    return (typeof value !== 'undefined') ? value.filter((item) => {   
      return item.company.startWith('s') || item.company_name.startWith('s') || item.another_index.startWith('s');
    }) : true;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! how would you extend this example for search a string over the hole object and not only a single index?

Comment: I have upadated my answer For multiple index you have to add your filter condition inside `filter` function. You can take reference from https://gist.github.com/ranakrunal9/092d6b930ede855e59e82c0f429fd562 to pass index as `pipe` parameter

Comment: thanks! that helps a lot. is there another way without list every key manually? I remember that works in angular 1. with the following syntax: | filter:searchTerm